# python postgresql create database and populate table from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

I am quite new to Python and also very new to using postgresql, so please forgive me if this is something basic (which I - so far - have failed to achieve). I'm trying to write a python code that:

- creates a new database (`testdb`)
- reads a csv file into a pandas dataframe
- creates and populates a new table within the database out of the pandas dataframe.

I have 3 different files so far: a) an `.ini`-File where I store the database info I need to create a new database, b) a `.csv`-File (from [here](http://eforexcel.com/wp/downloads-17-sample-csv-files-data-sets-for-testing-credit-card/), named `100_recs.csv`) and c) my python code.

**database.ini**:

```
[postgresql]
host=localhost
user=postgres
password=creator
port=5432
```

**db_creator.py**:

```
from config import config
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database
import pandas as pd

# useful info for psycopg2:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484066/create-a-postgres-database-using-python


class MyDB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.params = config()

    def create_new_db(self, newdb):
        user, host, port = self.params['user'], self.params['host'], testdb.params['port']
        pw = self.params['password']
        url = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'
        url = url.format(user, pw, host, port, newdb)

        engine = create_engine(url)
        if not database_exists(engine.url):
            create_database(engine.url)

        print(database_exists(engine.url))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    testdb = MyDB()
    testdb.create_new_db('testdb')
```

When I try to do it like that, I'm getting the following Error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError)

However, it works when I do it as suggested in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484066/create-a-postgres-database-using-python). Unfortunately, the answer in this post uses `psycopg2` to create a new database, but I would like to do it with `sqlalchemy` (also because I think that working with Pandas dataframe further on will be easier with `sqlalchemy` (as e.g. shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506578/how-to-create-a-new-database-using-sqlalchemy). Or am I wrong?). I thought that when doing it with `sqlqlchemy` then something like the following should be possible to read the data from the csv-file into a pandas dataframe and then populate a table in the new database:

```
def connect_alchemy(user, host, port, db, password):
    url = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'
    url = url.format(user, password, host, port, db)
    con = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url, client_encoding='utf8')
    mydata = pd.read_csv('100_recs.csv', delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    data_db = mydata.to_sql(name='100_records', con=con, if_exists='replace', index=True, chunksize=10)

    print(con.execute('SELECT * from 100_records'))
```

But honestly, I'm stuck here and need some help... It would be great if someone could point me into the right direction.

**EDIT**:
Ah stupid me! 
So I had an old typo in the follwing lines in `db_creator.py`

```
user, host, port = testdb.params['user'], testdb.params['host'], testdb.params['port']
        pw = testdb.params['password']
```

should be:

```
user, host, port = self.params['user'], self.params['host'], self.params['port']
        pw = self.params['password']
```

I already changed this.

Then I also forgot to add the `config.py` file here. Apologies for that.

Here you go:

**config.py**

```
# source: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/connect/
from configparser import ConfigParser


def config(filename='database.ini', section='postgresql'):
    # create a parser
    parser = ConfigParser()
    # read config file
    parser.read(filename)

    # get section, default to postgresql
    db = {}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        params = parser.items(section)
        for param in params:
            db[param[0]] = param[1]
    else:
        raise Exception('Section {0} not found in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))

    return db
```

**EDIT 2**:

It works now with the following setup:

**database.ini**:

```
[postgresql]
host=localhost
user=postgres
password=postgres
port=5432
```

**config.py**:

```
# source: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/connect/
from configparser import ConfigParser


def config(filename='database.ini', section='postgresql'):
    # create a parser
    parser = ConfigParser()
    # read config file
    parser.read(filename)

    # get section, default to postgresql
    db = {}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        params = parser.items(section)
        for param in params:
            db[param[0]] = param[1]
    else:
        raise Exception('Section {0} not found in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))

    return db
```

**the csv file**: from [here](http://eforexcel.com/wp/downloads-17-sample-csv-files-data-sets-for-testing-credit-card/)

**db_creator.py**

```
from config import config
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database
import pandas as pd

# useful info for psycopg2:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484066/create-a-postgres-database-using-python


class MyDB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.params = config()

    def create_new_db(self, newdb):
        user, host, port = self.params['user'], self.params['host'], self.params['port']
        pw = self.params['password']
        url = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'
        url = url.format(user, pw, host, port, newdb)

        self.engine = create_engine(url, client_encoding='utf8')
        if not database_exists(self.engine.url):
            create_database(self.engine.url)
        # print(database_exists(engine.url))

def df2postgres(engine, df):
    con = engine.connect()
    df.to_sql(name='records', con=con, if_exists='replace', index=True, chunksize=10)

    return con



if __name__ == '__main__':

    testdb = MyDB()
    testdb.create_new_db('testdb')
    engn = testdb.engine
    df = pd.read_csv('100_recs.csv', delimiter=';', quotechar='"', encoding='utf-8')
    con = df2postgres(engine=engn, df=df)
    dta = con.execute('SELECT * FROM records LIMIT 5;')
    print(dta.fetchall())
```

Apologies for the stupid mistakes...

Comment: The answers in the linked duplicate (also linked to in the question) are what is required, but care must be taken create the database outside of a transaction.  Up to SQLAlchemy 1.3.x this can be done by committing the connection prior to issuing the `CREATE DATABASE` statement.  In 2.0 style-code, the connection must be created as an autocommit connection, or `autocommit = True` must be set on the raw DB-API connector (and unset afterwards).  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28784334/5320906) shows how you might create such a connection.

Answer (score 0):

`psycopg2` is just a module that provides an adapter to connect to `Postgres` dbs using `python` code. On the other hand, `SQLAlcehmy` is an `Object Relational Mapper`. It provides an additional layer of abstraction that mirrors sql tables to python objects and standarizes the operations to move data between your code and your database.

You can make use of `psycopg2` and `sqlalchemy` at same time, as you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html)

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://scott:tiger@localhost/mydatabase')
```