# Python: How to create a database and define the username and password?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql

I am trying to create a postgresql database named `my_database` which will have `table_yesterday`, `table_today`, and `table_tomorrow`. I have never created a database before because I have only worked with `.csv` files.

The goal is to write a program that updates a few database tables that will be used by other programs, and if that database doesn't exist then create it and then download a ton of data into it.

How would I create a database with the `username` and `password` in my `config.py` file using python?

All the code I can find gives examples in `sqlite`.

Comment: do you have a psql server? sqlite is a file-based db thats easy to create on the fly, for psql or sqlserver you need a db server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a Postgres database using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484066/create-a-postgres-database-using-python)